# AWS S3 Event message structure version2.0

Tags: amazon-s3

Where can I find the specifications of all the fields in the version 2.0 of AWS S3 Event message structure.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html
This link talks about version 2.2

Or is there a changelog from version 2.0 to 2.2

Comment: The `glacierEventData` [property was added](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506140819/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html)